# Swift XCTest: Verify proper deallocation of weak variables

Tags: swift, xctest, weak, capture-list

Recently I was attempting to verify that an object I wrote properly deallocates using a unit test. I found however that no matter what I tried the object would not deallocate before the test completed. So I reduced the test to a trivial example (seen below) that attempts to prove the basics of object deallocation using weak variables.

In my mind, the strong reference should stop retaining the object after the test method exits, and the weak reference should be nil when referenced on the next run loop. However, the weak reference is never nil and both tests fail. Am I misunderstanding something here? Below are the unit tests in full.

```
class Mock { //class type, should behave with reference semantics

    init() { }
}

class DeallocationTests: XCTestCase {   

    func testWeakVarDeallocation() {   

        let strongMock = Mock()

        weak var weakMock: Mock? = strongMock

        let expt = expectation(description: "deallocated")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            XCTAssertNil(weakMock)      //This assertion fails

            expt.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0, handler: nil)
    }

    func testCaptureListDeallocation() {   

        let strongMock = Mock()

        let expt = expectation(description: "deallocated")

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak weakMock = strongMock] in

            XCTAssertNil(weakMock)      //This assertion also fails

            expt.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

I thought that maybe deallocation was being deferred somehow by XCTest, but even wrapping the test method bodies in an `autoreleasepool` did not cause the object to deallocate.

Comment: `weakMock` needs to be an optional, e.g. `weak var weakMock: Mock? = strongMock`.  If it can't be set to `nil` it can't be released.

Comment: @par `weakMock` is automatically optional which is enforced by the compiler. If you inspect the type of `weakMock`, it's already `Mock?` without the explicit type annotation.

Comment: And if you make it explicitly optional does it become nil?

Comment: @par It doesn't unfortunately. Will add type annotations to my example just for completeness. Thanks though

Comment: Then I think it's a synchronization issue. Since you are calling `waitForExpectations()` the `testWeakVarDeallocation()` function hasn't exited when your async block is called.  So a reference to `strongMock` is still held thus `weakMock` can't go to `nil`.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `testWeakVarDeallocation()` function hasn't exited when the `dispatchAsync` block is called so a strong reference to `strongMock` is still held.

Try it like this (allowing `testWeakVarDeallocation()` to exit) and you'll see `weakMock` becomes `nil` as expected:

```
class weakTestTests: XCTestCase {
    var strongMock: Mock? = Mock()

    func testWeakVarDeallocation() {
        weak var weakMock = strongMock

        print("weakMock is \(weakMock)")

        let expt = self.expectation(description: "deallocated")

        strongMock = nil

        print("weakMock is now \(weakMock)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            XCTAssertNil(weakMock)      // This assertion fails

            print("fulfilling expectation")
            expt.fulfill()
        }

        print("waiting for expectation")
        self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0, handler: nil)
        print("expectation fulfilled")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about why the object doesn't deallocate, but your solution doesn't fix the problem. The test completes and passes before the first async block is ever run, because there are no expectations being waited on. Quite the catch-22.

Comment: You're right, the XCTest function doesn't wait around.  I've updated the answer and it does the right thing now.

Comment: Yeah that works, I figured out the problem below using autoreleasepool, but your solution is essentially the same. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually it's different.  Swift objects aren't retained and autoreleased like you're familiar with in (old-style) Objective-C.  There is only reference counting due to scope.